# Searching an array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, javascript-objects

```
let teams = [
{ name : 'Patriots' },
{ name : 'Dolphins' },
{ name : 'Jets' }, 
{ name : 'Bills' }
]

let search = (name) => {
    for( let i = 0; i < teams.length; i++ ) {
        if( name === teams[i].name ) {
            return teams[i];
        }
        return false;
    }
}
console.log(search('Patriots')); // returns { name : 'Patriots }
console.log(search('Dolphins')); // return false
```

I am trying to write a search function to search an array of objects. When I search for the first object it returns it. When I search for any other object in the array it return false. Is there a way to have the `for loop` run completely before moving onto my if else statements or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Put the "return false" outside the for loop

Comment: wow... thanks @AlexBieg

Comment: Haha no worries. It happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove 'return false' from within the for loop, this is triggering after the loop has gone through the first value so it is never reaching 2,3,4th property/teams.

```
let teams = [
    { name : 'Patriots' },
    { name : 'Dolphins' },
    { name : 'Jets' }, 
    { name : 'Bills' }
]

let search = (name) => {
    for( let i = 0; i < teams.length; i++ ) {
        if( name === teams[i].name ) {
            return teams[i];
        }
    }
    // return 'false' if not found
    return false
}
console.log(search('Patriots')); // returns { name : 'Patriots }
console.log(search('Dolphins')); // returns { name : 'Dolphins }
console.log(search('Oranges'));  // returns false
```

`return teams[i];` will stop the loop from continuing once it has found a matching value.

I've added `return false` after the for loop, so If the team name is not found the function will return 'false'.

Comment: +1 but if the expectation is for it to return false if not found then you need to add return false after the for loop. That way the search either returns the result, or it iterates over the array and then returns false. I'd also suggest using https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Liam, ive updated answer to include this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with filter and reduce.

```js
const teams = [
    { name : 'Patriots' },
    { name : 'Dolphins' },
    { name : 'Jets' }, 
    { name : 'Bills' }
]
const search = (arr, s) => arr.filter(({name}) => name === s).reduce((p,{name}) => name || p, false) 

console.log(search(teams, 'Patriots'))
```